# getting Cree IDN accepted by gmail

Tags: internationalization, smtp, gmail, idn

Any clues on how to get first nations IDNs accepted by gmail? Specifically, these are IDNs using Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics. Google's SMTP servers bounce email from these IDNs, complaining that the IDNs "use a domain name that does not meet our domain name policies." Digging into the RFCs from the IETF and the docs over at unicode.org indicates these IDNs should be fine (allowed at the highly restrictive level) because the characters are "PVALID" (protocol valid) and the IDNs only use a single script.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a work around? I haven't found any other than using icloud and other non-google services. Yes, Apple supports the first nations of north america. Cool, eh?

I know this use case is rare in that these languages are on the brink of extinction (but making a comeback!). It's just a shame because Google's lack of IDN support is yet another reason that first nations people feel excluded.

The good news is that the noto fonts appear to now include all the Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics. So we can write 'em, but can't fully use 'em.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by using a second domain and rewriting email headers. It's a sucky solution, but that's life. Here it is:

DomainA is the one that google's filters improperly reject. DomainB is a rough translation into English or other language that google deems worthy. Set an SMTP server to receive traffic from domainA and domainB. Users are configured to use this as their outgoing SMTP server. When email from domainA arrives, check the destination MX record. If it goes to "*.google.com" or a similarly limited provider, then rewrite the header to change DomainA to DomainB, then treat normally. Also, when email from domainB arrives and the destination mx record shows domainA will be treated properly, rewrite to domainA and then treat normally.

This way, users in google's garden will still receive emails while everyone else can enjoy using first nations IDNs.